# How to remove a path segment from NGiNX fastcgi_script_name?

Tags: php, regex, nginx

This question could also be: **"How to modify an NGiNX variable with a RegEx?"**,
or: **"Can RegEx backreference have gaps?"**

Either of those would resolve the problem I'm having. Perhaps a really simple solution exists, and after digging the web for few hours, it's time to ask for help.

Here's the scenario:

There's a part of the request URI that is going to be present always (for a sort of a gimmicky domain name + URI combination :-).  I enforce the presence of that always-present URI path component, which follows immediately after the domain name, like so:

http://somedomain.com/basepart/rest/of/the/path?q=123

In the above example the "/basepart" represents the always-present URI component.

So far so good. The problem arises when I want the base file path to be `/var/www/somedomain.com/htdocs/` without the `basepart`, and php5_fpm proxy is used. I obviously set:

```
    location /basepart {
            alias /var/www/somedomain.com/htdocs;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
```

But since the dynamic files are in PHP, I need to either use `fastcgi_split_path_info` or `$request_uri` to build/pass the `SCRIPT_FILENAME` to php5_fpm. How do I do that? How do I remove the `/basepart` from `$fastcgi_script_name`, or from `$request_uri`, as otherwise PHP will look for the file in `/var/www/somedomain.com/htdocs/basepart`?

I've considered named backreferences, or "collecting" or "fragmented" backreferences (which I don't think exist in regex) so that I could capture the segment in `$fastcgi_script_name` before and after the basepart when `fastcgi_split_path_info` assignment happens, but haven't got them to work. *Dayo* [writes earlier at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12057752/134536): »Nginx is a webserver and not a scripting application.», and suggests use of Lua for more complex scripting. But I have a feeling I may be overlooking some really simple, facepalm-worthy solution :-].

Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `alias` directive is fine for static websites but not so useful when PHP is involved. My preferred solution is to internally rewrite the URI without the `/basepart` and then use `root` rather than `alias`.

The problem is that many PHP scripts use `$request_uri` in order to process the request, which is frozen with the `/basepart` intact. However, we can specify any value we choose for `REQUEST_URI` and construct a more appropriate value from `$uri` or captures. In the example below, I preserve the value of `$uri` after the first rewrite so that it can be used to pass our modified *request URI* to the PHP script.

```
root /var/www/somedomain.com/htdocs;

location ^~ /basepart {
    rewrite ^/basepart/(.*)$ /$1 last;
    rewrite ^ / last;
}

location / {
    internal;
    try_files $uri @index;
}

location @index {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
    ...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    internal;
    try_files $uri @index;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
    ...
}
```

The `fastcgi` code block is duplicated across two locations. If it becomes unwieldy, the common code can be placed into a separate include file.

Locations are made private by using the `internal` directive keeping the `/basepart` mandatory for external access.

Comment: with the New Year celebrations done, I had time to step through your response more in detail, and it did resolve my issue. I also like the way to structure "@index" condition; it makes the configuration cleaner. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

If someone else stumbles on this question, after some brainstorming i came up with stupidly obvious solution:

```
    root /app/frontend/web/;
    location /api/ {
        alias /app/backend/web/;
        index index.php index.html;
        # Double /api/ because "that's how nginx alias and try_files works together"
        try_files $uri /api//api/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~ ^/api(/.*\.php(?:\?.*)?)$ {
            try_files $uri /api//api/index.php$is_args$args;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
            ...
        }
    }
```

I.e. using regex capturing group.

With this rules requests will be routed following way:

```
  /index.html -> /app/frontend/web/index.html
  /test/test.php -> /app/frontend/web/test/test.php as plaintext
  /api/<somepath> -> /app/backend/web/<somepath> (proxied to FPM if .php) if it exists, otherwise /app/backend/web/index.php
```