# Nginx, location, alias and php

Tags: nginx, lighttpd, nginx-location

We are moving from lighttpd to nginx for HTTP/2.0 and having hard time configuring something which was so simple in lighttpd.

```
alias.url    = ("/api" => "/web/myserver.com/develapi/")
```

We do this as we version control api and then just point url to appropriate folder. We do not want to use file links as well. Moreover, it's an one line command in lighttpd.

Here is how we are trying to achieve the same in NGINX.

```
location /api {
     alias   /web/myserver.com/develapi;
     location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     }
    }
```

However, this does not work as nginx passes /web/myserver.com/develapi as $document_root and /api/index.php as $fastcgi_script_name and hence resulting SCRIPT_FILENAME is wrong.

We then tried to use root

```
location /develapi {
     root   /web/myserver.com;
     location ~ \.php$ {
       fastcgi_index  index.php;
       fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
       include        fastcgi_params;
       fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
     }
    }
```

This works as nginx passes /web/myserver.com as $document_root and /develapi/index.php $fastcgi_script_name and hence resulting SCRIPT_FILENAME is correct.

However, using root means either we have change existing structure or url. For this situation, using alias is the right solution but the way nginx implementing it, makes it tricky to use alias.

May be we are missing something trivial, any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It has been 3+ years... hope you have found the answer by now!
Here is a solution, for similar problem where I wanted to rewrite the fastcgi_script_name stripping off "wiki/" in front of them.

```
        location /wiki {
        alias  C:/opt/mw/mediawiki-1.36.1;
        index  index.html index.php index.htm;          
        location ~ ^/wiki(/.*\.php(?:\?.*)?)$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$1;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    }
```

Got the inspiration from: [How to remove a path segment from NGiNX fastcgi_script_name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523295/how-to-remove-a-path-segment-from-nginx-fastcgi-script-name)

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is commonly answered/documented way to return SCRIPT_FILENAME

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Reading more docs reveals $request_filename is a better way to go and works in both root and alias

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```